# Function cannot return item with Coroutine block

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I am retrieving a record from a Room database using `Coroutines` because it has to run in a background thread. I want to return the result through the function.

```
class LessonRepository(val app: Application) {

    private val courseDao = MyDatabase.getDatabase(app).courseDao()
}

    fun getCourseData(): Course {

        var course: Course

        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            course = courseDao.getCourse(globalSelectedCourse)
        }
        return course
    }
```

ViewModel

```
class LessonViewModel(app: Application): AndroidViewModel(app) {

    private val lessonDataRepository = LessonRepository(app)
    val lessonData = lessonDataRepository.lessonData
    val selectedLesson = MutableLiveData<Lesson>()

    fun getCourseData() : Course {
        return lessonDataRepository.getCourseData()
    }
}
```

I want to use the return value in my fragment:

```
class DetailFragment : Fragment(), LessonRecyclerAdapter.LessonItemListener {
.
.
.
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(LessonViewModel::class.java)

        val course = viewModel.getCourseData()
.
.
.
    }
```

However, Android Studio is giving me an error indicator in the return statement `return course` that `course` must be initialized. How can i successfuly return the value of `course`?

**-- UPDATE: --**

I am trying to get a value of that record and use it in my fragment as follows:

```
val course = viewModel.viewModelScope.launch { viewModel.getCourseData() }

textViewName.text = course.Name
textViewInstructor.text = course.instructor
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take advantage of the coroutines support that Room provides since version 2.1.0. The official documentation states:

> You can add the suspend Kotlin keyword to your DAO methods to make
>   them asynchronous using Kotlin coroutines functionality. This ensures
>   that they cannot be executed on the main thread.

You can check that [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#kotlin-coroutines).

So you should add suspend keyword to your `getCourse` DAO method:

**DAO interface**

```
@Query("MY SQL QUERY")
suspend fun getCourse(selectedCourse: SelectedCourseType): Course
```

If you do that then you can just return the result no matter if you make the request on the main thread:

**Repository**

```
suspend fun getCourseData() = courseDao.getCourse(globalSelectedCourse)
```

**ViewModel**

```
suspend fun getCourseData() = lessonDataRepository.getCourseData()
```

You also should use `lifecycleScope` which is available on Fragments as you can see [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#lifecyclescope):

**Fragment**

```
fun doSomething() {
    ...    
    viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
        val course = viewModel.getCourseData()
        textViewName.text = course.Name
        textViewInstructor.text = course.instructor
    }
    ...    
}
```

**PS:** Consider passing the selected course as argument through the whole chain of calls instead of using a global variable on your repo.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I am actually using suspend on mentioned functions except the DAO.so i did add it and followed your suggestion by using ...  viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope because the app sometimes crashes.

Comment: While @Animesh Sahu's answer is correct and did work, however, on some occasions the app crashed, probably because some DAO methods ran on the main thread. So i will accept this as the full working answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing this the wrong way. Maybe you have some misconceptions about concurrency, or tasks which run concurrently.

Let me clear your doubts.

1. launch does not block, it is launch and forget. You never know when the value is set. Only thing you can do is call `join()` on that to make sure it is done.
2. But still using a launch block is not very well optimized for tasks where you want a result back from a coroutine. We use async/withContext here.
3. `async` is called on a CoroutineScope while a `withContext` is a top level function which expects a CoroutineContext as its parameter.
4. `withContext` suspends the caller coroutine till it is completed. While the `async` does not, the return value of `async` is `Deferred<T>` on which when you call `.await()` the caller coroutine gets suspended till it the task is completed similar to withContext.

So you can do your task in the following way.

**Option 1: The most optimized version**

Make your function suspend and use withContext. It will suspend the calling coroutine till the course is fetched.

```kotlin
suspend fun getCourseData(): Course {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        courseDao.getCourse(globalSelectedCourse)
    }
}

// or simpler
suspend fun getCourseData(): Course =
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        courseDao.getCourse(globalSelectedCourse)
    }
```

**Option 2: Use async, and return the Deferred.**

```kotlin
// declare scope elsewhere. It is not intended to create scope everytime you want to launch a task
val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)

// using async at the end of function is a naming scheme by Kotlin recommendation.
fun getCourseDataAsync(): Deferred<Course> =
    scope.async {
        courseDao.getCourse(globalSelectedCourse)
    }

//Now when you call the function, call await(), it is suspending, it will suspend the calling coroutine till the course is fetched.
val course: Course = getCourseDataAsync().await()
```

#### Update on OP's update

As i also suggested in the comments, you cannot take a suspending block of code outside the coroutine block. Because you can not suspend a non-suspending function.

Do as follows:

```kotlin
// in fragment
suspend fun getCourseData() : Course {
    return lessonDataRepository.getCourseData()
}

viewModel.viewModelScope.launch {
    val course = viewModel.getCourseData()

    textViewName.text = course.Name
    textViewInstructor.text = course.instructor
}
```

Comment: I cannot use a suspend function because i am calling it from my fragment

Comment: @Ajeeli you can call any suspend function inside a coroutine. For instance in a fragment you can call `viewModelOwner.viewModelScope.launch{/* call here */}`

Comment: I may not have been very clear in my question, so i have updated it

Comment: i did follow your first option, and the program did run, however the value of "course" was incorrect

Comment: val course = viewModel.viewModelScope.launch { viewModel.getCourseData() }

Comment: @Ajeeli you cannot get the data outside the coroutine. `viewModel.viewModelScope.launch { val cource = viewModel.getCourseData() }` Since the callsite function (from where you calling it) does not suspend, there is no [Continuation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines.experimental/-continuation/) there.

Comment: What i am trying to achieve is to retrieve a single record from the database and use that record info in my fragment

Comment: @Ajeeli can you provide how you are using the course / want to use it outside the coroutine in order to help you further, please edit your question.

Comment: @Ajeeli updated the answer for fitting with your usecase!